# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent Relationship for a table with two user id columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've got a sports app that has a list of `Competitors (competitors table`) and a `Match (matches table)` where in a match there are two competitors so the matches table has a column for `player with hasOne competitor relationship`, and another column for `opponent with hasOne competitor relationship`, which seemed okay at first, but the relationships for the Match model would have to look like this:

**Current Match Model**

```
public function player()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Competitor');
}

public function opponent()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Competitor');
}
```

Instead of something like this:

**Ideal Match Model**

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Competitor');
}
```

and the relationship for the Competitors model gets even uglier with:

**Current Competitors Model**

```
public function playerMatch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Match', 'player_id');
}

public function opponentMatch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Match', 'opponent_id');
}
```

Instead of something like this:

**Ideal Competitors Model**

```
public function match()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Match');
}
```

If there weren't two columns one for each player this would look the way it should and get all the players matches, or get the player(s) in a match using eager loading or whatever, but that isn't the case.

I'd like to be able to just use `belongsTo match` and `hasMany competitors` like I've outlined above, but I'm not sure how to make this work other than just get each result separately then merging them before carrying on, or if it is even possible to do the ideal?  Does it mean reconfiguring the database tables?

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. How do you solve this problem? If `competitor` holds `match` `foreign key`, `competitor` will be attach to only 1 `match`. That is not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should reconfigure the tables so that a `Competitor` holds a foreign key for the `Match` and not the other way around and then just add something like a `competitor_type` field that can have either a `player` or `opponent` value. That way a `Match` `hasMany` `Competitor`, a `Competitor` `belongsTo` a `Match` and a `Competitor` can either be a `player` or `opponent`.

**UPDATE**

For the `Match` model to have a reference to each type of `Competitor`, you can do the following:

```php
public function competitors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Competitor');
}

public function player()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Competitor')->where('competitor_type', 'player');
}

public function opponent()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Competitor')->where('competitor_type', 'opponent');
}
```

So you can use `Eloquent` methods on it and do something like: `$match->player->name` or `$match->opponent->name`.

Comment: Hi, how would a single match have a reference to two players this way

Comment: Hi, I like it.  I didn't think to chain like that in the method.  Are you able to do something like this? `return $this->hasOne('App\Competitor', 'competitor_id', 'player_id')->hasOne('App\Competitor', 'competitor_id', 'opponent_id');` to get a list of all competitors.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can't chain relationship methods. Why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: Due to the Matches table having a players and opponents columns, but in all cases outside the database I don't actually care if they are a player or opponent (at least not at the moment for basic CRUD) I just want to get all the competitors in a match regardless, which in this case would be two competitor ids, but from different columns.  Similarly, in reverse I just want a competitors match regardless of whether they are a player or opponent.

Comment: My solution would require you to move the foreign key from the `matches` table to the `competitors` table. If you implement the `Match` model relationships I posted above, you can get all `competitors` in a match by doing something like `$match->competitors` and it should return a `Collection` of `App\Competitor`s. For the reverse, you can set up your `App\Competitor` model using your __ideal__ way and can do something like `$competitor->match`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely do that instead.

Comment: The only issue now is I can't associated competitors to multiple matches since in tournaments they will be in a dozen or more preset matches.  Maybe I shouldn't be using Eloquent and instead use DB Builder, get the players, get the opponents, then merge them, and vice versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92924/discussion-between-sandyandi-n-dela-cruz-and-mtpultz).